# How can I have @AspectJ target specific subclasses when method signature has parent class?

Tags: aop, aspectj

Say I have a method signature that is

```
public void accept(ParentInterface parent)
```

where ParentInterface is an interface. I want my pointcut to only specifically target a class TestA, but not a class TestB, both which implement the ParentInterface.

Currently, I have the following pointcut:

```
@Pointcut("call(public void accept(package.ParentInterface))")
```

But that would catch instances where accept is taking in a TestB instance too. Is there a method of fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

**Interface + implementations + driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public interface ParentInterface {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class TestA implements ParentInterface {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class TestB implements ParentInterface {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
    public void accept(ParentInterface parent) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application application = new Application();
        application.accept(new TestA());
        application.accept(new TestB());
    }
}
```

**Aspect pinning down argument type via `args()` + pointcut method signature:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

import de.scrum_master.app.TestA;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
    @Pointcut("call(public void accept(de.scrum_master.app.ParentInterface)) && args(argument)")
    static void acceptCalls(TestA argument) {}

    @Before("acceptCalls(argument)")
    public void intercept(TestA argument, JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint + " -> " + argument);
    }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
call(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.accept(ParentInterface)) -> de.scrum_master.app.TestA@4a574795
```